# monit: use hostname in logfile path

Tags: monit

I am new to monit and want to use different logfile path for monit (not the default one)

```
set logfile /x/home/xxxx/yyyy/monit/monit-5.20.0/logs/monit_$HOST.log
```

In place of **$HOST**, I want the hostname where the monit is running.
Any idea how can we achieve this? Similarly, I wan to use the hostname for idfile and statefile as well.

**Note:**  `/x/home/xxxx/yyyy/monit/monit-5.20.0` is common mount for all machines and want to run monit on them. But don't want the same log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the way to have hostname in the logfile, idfile and statsfile.
I created a wrapper script `start.sh` as follows and started the monit by passing control file, logfile, idfile and statsfile.

```
#!/bin/bash

BASEDIR=`dirname $0`
HOST=`hostname`
MONIT_BIN=$BASEDIR/bin/monit
CTRL_FILE=$BASEDIR/conf/monitrc
LOG_FILE=$BASEDIR/logs/monit_$HOST.log
PID_FILE=$BASEDIR/run/monit_$HOST.pid
STATS_FILE=$BASEDIR/run/.monit_$HOST.state

mkdir -p $BASEDIR/run
mkdir -p $BASEDIR/logs

touch $PID_FILE
touch $STATS_FILE
touch $LOG_FILE

nohup $MONIT_BIN -c $CTRL_FILE -l $LOG_FILE -p $PID_FILE -s $STATS_FILE &> /dev/null &
```